# Error encountered while trying to run a powershell script with multiline string in Jupyterlabs

Tags: powershell, jupyter-notebook

I want to save this java code snippet to a file (Demo.java) using PowerShell script in Jupyterlab:

Code snippet:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world, this is a really simple Java program!");
    }
}
```

Running the code from Windows PowerShell works just fine:

```
$"public class Demo {`n`tpublic static void main(String[] args) {`n`t`tSystem.out.println(`"Hello world, this is a really simple Java program!`");`n`t}`n}" > C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/javacode/Demo.java
```

Running this from my notebook doesn't:

```
!powershell Set-Content -Path C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/javacode/Demo.java -Value "public class Demo {`n`tpublic static void main(String[] args) {`n`t`tSystem.out.println(\`"Hello world, this is a really simple Java program!\`" );`n`t}`n}"
```

Neither does the first code above. It produces this error:

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'class'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Content -Path C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/javacode/De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

It appears that I am not properly delimiting the inner quotes in the code snippet above. I suppose backticks are used to delimit quotes in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `\"...\"` to enclose the *entire* argument passed to `-Value`.
- Use `` `\"...`\" `` to enclose the string *embedded* in that argument.

```
!powershell -c Set-Content -Path C:/Users/user_name/Desktop/javacode/Demo.java -Value \"public class Demo {`n`tpublic static void main(String[] args) {`n`t`tSystem.out.println(`\"Hello world, this is a really simple Java program!`\" );`n`t}`n}\"
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @paranorman_einstein; my pleasure. Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment: